# What is the best way to catch and show an error if user enters only whitespace in a form field in Django?

Tags: regex, django, validation, forms, field

In Django 1.0, what is the best way to catch and show an error if user enters only whitespace (" ") in a form field?

```
class Item(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ItemForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
```

if user enters only whitespace (" ") in description CharField, what change needs to done to class Item or class ItemForm so that form.is_valid() fails and shows an error?

After form.is_valid(), I could write the code to check for only whitespaces in description field and raise a validation error but there has to be a better way. Can RegexField be used to specify description entered should not be just whitespaces. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item

    def clean_description(self):
        if not self.cleaned_data['description'].strip():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Your error message here')
```

The [forms validation documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#ref-forms-validation) might provide a good read.

Comment: Carl, thanks for posting an answer. I have posted a short one line update to the class, that solves the issue. I was not familiar enough with modelform to see how RegexField would work in this case. Asking on django irc & reading http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields again sorted it.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Just adding **description = forms.RegexField(regex=r'[^(\s+)]')** to class ItemForm will cause the form.is_valid() to fail and show the error

```
class ItemForm(ModelForm):
    description = forms.RegexField(regex=r'[^(\s+)]')
    class Meta:
        model = Item
```

To include your own message, add error_message=... to forms.RegexField

```
description = forms.RegexField(regex=r'[^(\s+)]', error_message=_("Your error message here."))
```

Answer (score 1):

why regex? just use `str.strip()` to check if a string consists of only whitespace